# How do you make an onTouchListener keep going as long as the view is being pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I am using a small square `RelativeLayout` as a game pad for movement in a neighboring `GLSurfaceView`.

I set it up so that in the `onTouch` method of the `RelativeLayout`'s `onTouchListenner` I call a method built into the `GLSurfaceView` that updates the translation and rotation coordinates for my drawing.

I have everything working fine, except for the fact that touch events are only triggered if the user moves his or her finger on the `RelativeLayout`.

I would like it to feel a little bit like a joystick: if you leave your finger pressed on the top of the RelativeLayout, then you will keep going "up" ( or more programatically: the `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` that were sent last should get looped, or re-sent, in the `GLSurfaceView` until the user either moves his finger inside the `RelativeLayout`, or stops touching the `RelativeLayout` altogether.)

What should I use to detect whether or not the `RelativeLayout` is currently being touched (even if there is no motion in the said touch)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the event.getAction() method of the MotionEvent parameter of your onTouch() method. You can check to see if it is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN or MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    //start something
}
else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    //stop something
}
```

My thought is that you might be able to start or stop a thread in this manner but either way this might at least give you some more information about when the user actually presses and lifts his/her finger.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I came up pretty much simultaneously with csmcklvey

```
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                gM.isTouchedL = false;
            else
                gM.isTouchedL = true;
            return true;
```

Where .isTouchedL is the "control boolean" I use in the GLSurfaceView

Green lit csmc's answer anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used rotation animation in one of my apps, which is using the onTouchEven of view. Major function has been performed in event "ACTION_MOVE". It will help you, to get through.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{

  final float xc = volumeButton.getWidth() / 2;
  final float yc = volumeButton.getHeight() / 2;
  final float x = event.getX();
  final float y = event.getY();
  switch (event.getAction()) 
  {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     {
//      volumeButton.clearAnimation();
//      mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
        break;
     }
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
     {
        mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
        mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
        animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 100);
        break;
     }
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
     {
        mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;
        break;
     }
  }
  return true;

}
```